# Checkbox for gridview inside listview in Android

Tags: android, listview, gridview, checkbox

I have a problem statement in my booking app such that user can delete all the booking of the particular date or all the dates, see this image:

[image: here]

I have tried to add data to the grid view using multiple adapters for listview and the inner gridview, but it's taking data replication. How can I solve this problem?

Each date represents the listview with checkbox,and the UH,U1 etc represents the item of gridview. I want to pass the selected venue id ie. UH,U! etc in a listview and its corresponding dates

Answer (score 1):

Try the sample below :)

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

Button clearChecks;
ExpandableListView expandableListView;
ExpandableListGridAdapter expandableListAdapter;
int lastExpandedPosition = -1;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    expandableListView = findViewById(R.id.expandedListView);
    clearChecks = findViewById(R.id.btnClearChecks);

    List<String> listTitle = genGroupList();
    expandableListAdapter = new ExpandableListGridAdapter(this, listTitle, genChildList(listTitle));
    expandableListView.setAdapter(expandableListAdapter);

    expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            if(lastExpandedPosition != -1 && (lastExpandedPosition != groupPosition)){
                expandableListView.collapseGroup(lastExpandedPosition);
            }
            lastExpandedPosition = groupPosition;
        }
    });
    clearChecks.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            expandableListAdapter.clearChecks();
        }
    });
}

private List<String> genGroupList(){
    List<String> listGroup = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i=1; i<10; i++){
        listGroup.add("Group: " + i);
    }
    return listGroup;
}

private Map<String, List<ChildItemSample>> genChildList(List<String> header){
    Map<String, List<ChildItemSample>> listChild = new HashMap<>();
    for(int i=0; i<header.size(); i++){
        List<ChildItemSample> testDataList = new ArrayList<>();
        int a = (int)(Math.random() * 8);
        for(int j=0; j<a; j++){
            ChildItemSample testItem = new ChildItemSample("Child " + (j + 1));
            testDataList.add(testItem);
        }
        listChild.put(header.get(i), testDataList);
    }
    return  listChild;
}

}
```

ChildItemSample.java:

```
public class ChildItemSample {
private boolean checked;
private String name;

public boolean isChecked() {
    return checked;
}

public void setChecked(boolean checked) {
    this.checked = checked;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public ChildItemSample(){
    checked = false;
    name = "";
}

public ChildItemSample(String name){
    checked = false;
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

ExpandableListGridAdapter.java:

```
public class ExpandableListGridAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private Context context;
private List<String> listGroup;
private Map<String, List<ChildItemSample>> listChild;
private int checkedBoxesCount;
private boolean[] checkedGroup;

public ExpandableListGridAdapter(Context context, List<String> listGroup, Map<String,
        List<ChildItemSample>> listChild) {
    this.context = context;
    this.listGroup = listGroup;
    this.listChild = listChild;
    checkedBoxesCount = 0;
    checkedGroup = new boolean[listGroup.size()];
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return listGroup.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return 1;
}

@Override
public String getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return listGroup.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public ChildItemSample getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return listChild.get(listGroup.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    String itemGroup = getGroup(groupPosition);
    GroupViewHolder groupViewHolder;
    if(view == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.expanded_list_group, null);
        groupViewHolder = new GroupViewHolder();
        groupViewHolder.tvGroup = view.findViewById(R.id.tv_group);
        groupViewHolder.cbGroup = view.findViewById(R.id.cb_group);
        groupViewHolder.cbGroup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int pos = (int)view.getTag();
                checkedGroup[pos] = !checkedGroup[pos];
                for(ChildItemSample item : listChild.get(listGroup.get(pos))){
                    item.setChecked(checkedGroup[pos]);
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
        view.setTag(groupViewHolder);
    }else {
        groupViewHolder = (GroupViewHolder)view.getTag();
    }
    groupViewHolder.tvGroup.setText(String.format("%s (%d)", itemGroup, listChild.get(listGroup.get(groupPosition)).size()));
    if(checkedGroup[groupPosition]) groupViewHolder.cbGroup.setChecked(true);
    else groupViewHolder.cbGroup.setChecked(false);
    groupViewHolder.cbGroup.setTag(groupPosition);
    return view;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean b, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_grid_item, null);
    GridLayout childLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.layout_child);

    for(int i = 0; i < listChild.get(listGroup.get(groupPosition)).size(); i++){
        ChildItemSample expandedListText = getChild(groupPosition, i);
        CheckBox cbChild = new CheckBox(context);
        GridLayout.LayoutParams params = new GridLayout.LayoutParams();
        params.width = (int)(80 * context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density);
        cbChild.setLayoutParams(params);
        cbChild.setChecked(expandedListText.isChecked());
        cbChild.setText(expandedListText.getName());
        cbChild.setTag(i);
        childLayout.addView(cbChild);

        cbChild.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) view;
                int pos = (int) view.getTag();;
                ChildItemSample selectedItem = listChild.get(listGroup.get(groupPosition)).get(pos);
                selectedItem.setChecked(cb.isChecked());
                if(cb.isChecked()){
                    checkedBoxesCount++;
                    Toast.makeText(context,"Checked value is: " +
                                    listChild.get(listGroup.get(groupPosition)).get(pos).getName(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }else {
                    checkedBoxesCount--;
                    if(checkedBoxesCount == 0){
                        Toast.makeText(context,"nothing checked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }else {
                        Toast.makeText(context,"unchecked",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
                notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
    return view;
}

public void clearChecks() {
    for(int i=0; i<checkedGroup.length; i++) checkedGroup[i] = false;
    for(List<ChildItemSample> value : listChild.values()) {
        for (ChildItemSample sample : value) {
            sample.setChecked(false);
        }
    }
    checkedBoxesCount = 0;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}

private class GroupViewHolder {
    CheckBox cbGroup;
    TextView tvGroup;
}

}
```

activity_main.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClearChecks"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Clear Checks" />

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expandedListView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </ExpandableListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

expanded_list_group.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/cb_group"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_group"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Text"
    android:textSize="30sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

list_grid_item.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<GridLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/layout_child"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingStart="60dp"
android:columnCount="3"
android:orientation="horizontal">

</GridLayout>
```

Hope that helps!