# I want to know how to properly use adapters that connect Expandable List View and adapters that connect gridView at the same time

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

What I want to implement is putting a GridView in the Expandable List.
Currently, my code has two adapters called "CustomListAdapter" that connects the GridView to the Expandable List and "SiteAdapter" which connects the data to the GridView.
The code that we have built so far is well connected to the Expandable List to the GridView. However, the data inside the gridView seems to be connected to the gridView (seeing the items in the gridview and clicking on the appropriate link), but the image and text that make up the gridview's internal design do not appear on the screen. 
I have used setImage and setText inside the adapter code called "siteAdapter", but I do not know why it is not configured properly on the screen.

1] SiteAdapter.java (the siteAdapter code that links the GridView and the items)

```
public class SiteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Site> {
private Site currentSite;

public SiteAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Site> sites) {
    super(context, 0, sites);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View listItemView = convertView;
    if(listItemView == null){
        listItemView = LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item,parent,false);
    }
    currentSite = getItem(position);

    ImageView imageView = (ImageView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.image);
    imageView.setBackground(new ShapeDrawable(new OvalShape()));
    imageView.setClipToOutline(true);
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);

    TextView name = (TextView) listItemView.findViewById(R.id.name);
    name.setText(currentSite.getMsite_name());

    return listItemView;
}
```

2] CustomListAdapter.java (links the ExpandableList and the GridView)

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<String> arrayGroup;
private HashMap<String,ArrayList<Site>> arrayChild;

public CustomListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> arrayGroup, HashMap<String, ArrayList<Site>> arrayChild){
    super();
    this.mContext = context;
    this.arrayGroup = arrayGroup;
    this.arrayChild = arrayChild;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return arrayGroup.size();
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return arrayChild.get(arrayGroup.get(groupPosition)).size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return arrayGroup.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition)
{
    return arrayChild.get(arrayGroup.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition){
    return childPosition;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String groupName = arrayGroup.get(groupPosition);
    View v = convertView;

    if(v==null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.parent_listview_title, null);
    }
    TextView textGroup = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.title_site_list);
    textGroup.setText(groupName);

    return v;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
    String groupName = arrayGroup.get(groupPosition);
    View v = convertView;

    if(v == null){
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        v = (LinearLayout)inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_gridview_item, null);
    }
    SiteAdapter siteAdapter = new SiteAdapter(mContext,arrayChild.get(groupName));
    GridView gridView = (GridView) v.findViewById(R.id.gridView);
    gridView.setAdapter(siteAdapter);


    return v;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}
```

}

3] site_list.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical">
<ExpandableListView
    android:id="@+id/parentList"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

</ExpandableListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

4] parent_listview_title.xml(Code that designed the parent list of the Expandable List)

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/title_site_list"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="40sp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:textColor="#000000"
    android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
    android:fontFamily="@font/bm_dohyeon"
    android:textStyle="bold"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

5] child_gridview_item.xml(Code that designed the child list of the Expandable List)

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
<ViewSwitcher
    android:id="@+id/visibility"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="180dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp">
    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="3dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        />
    <GridView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        tools:context=".home"
        android:id="@+id/gridView"
        android:columnWidth="96dp"
        android:numColumns="4"
        android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
        android:horizontalSpacing="4dp"
        android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
        android:gravity="center"/>
</ViewSwitcher>
</LinearLayout>
```

6] list_item.xml(The code that designs the contents of the gridview, the child list of the Expandable List)

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_gravity="center"
>
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    tools:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    />
<TextView
    android:layout_width="60dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/name"
    tools:text="Gistsite"
    android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:textSize="4sp"
    />
</LinearLayout>
```

7] Site.java

```
public class Site {
private String msite_name;
private String msite_url;
private String msite_urlF;
private String msite_urlY;
private String msite_urlB;
private String msite_urlW;
private String msite_urlI;
private int msite_imagesource;

public Site(String name, String url, int imagesource){
    msite_name = name;
    msite_url = url;
    msite_imagesource = imagesource;
}

public Site(String name, String urlf, String urly, int imagesource){
    msite_name = name;
    msite_urlF = urlf;
    msite_urlY = urly;
    msite_imagesource = imagesource;
}

public Site(String name, String urlw, String urlb, String urlf, String urli,int imagesource){
    msite_name = name;
    msite_urlW = urlw;
    msite_urlB = urlb;
    msite_urlF = urlf;
    msite_urlI = urli;
    msite_imagesource = imagesource;
}

public String getMsite_name() {
    return this.msite_name;
}
public String getMsite_url(){
    return this.msite_url;
}
public String getMsite_urlW(){
    return this.msite_urlW;
}
public String getMsite_urlB(){ return this.msite_urlB; }
public String getMsite_urlF(){
    return this.msite_urlF;
}
public String getMsite_urlY(){
    return this.msite_urlY;
}
public String getMsite_urlI(){
    return this.msite_urlI;
}
public int getMsite_imagesource(){
    return this.msite_imagesource;
}
```

In summary, the problem is that the contents of the image view and text view designed in list_item.xml are not available.

Comment: When using gridview to show child list, **getChildrenCount** should use `return 1;` instead of `return arrayChild.get(arrayGroup.get(groupPosition)).size();`. By the way, I don't see what is **bitmap** inside SiteAdapter? Also please show how you set up your child list in activity. If the child list is not perpared correctly, then nothing will be shown. You may refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51868333/gridview-within-expandablelistview-with-database/51887911#51887911 Hope that helps!