# Possibilities of custom expandable list

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

I'm trying to add an Expandable List to my app, with a custom layout (containing two `ImageView` and two `TextView`) as a child. But I don't really understand how custom adapters work, so I would like to know if what I want to do is actually possible. Here is what the child layout has to look like (not very accurate in little details, but you can get the idea) :
[image]

Of course, I want every widget (both images and texts) to change according to the data I provide. Those informations are stored in objects : I basically want to display two objects on the same row. What adapter should I use ? I saw in some tutorials that they use HashMaps to link the header to the child, but here the child isn't one object.

I'm a little bit lost, I hope I was clear enough.

Comment: If you want multiple children in a row, these links may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49914836/checkbox-for-gridview-inside-listview-in-android  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50288713/expandablelistview-with-viewpager-combination-as-its-child

Comment: that was perfect, thank you very much !